# implement smooth swiping between panels left and right like a mobile application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have made a user interface with many panels of the same size (9:16 aspect ratio) for mobile devices. each panel has different elements and information like what the app does, some buttons, images and so on.

the idea is to be able to swipe left and right between all these panels to display the panel i need.

i have made a code that allowed me to enable and disable panels depending on if i swipe left or right. i implemented that code using **OnDrag** and **OnDragEnd**, but i did not like the result. it did not feel like a real mobile application would do it because when i swipe left or right there is no smooth transition between them it just replaces the current active panel to another one.

i was hoping someone here can help me by telling me how to implement smooth swiping using **OnDrag **and **OnDragEnd**

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you're probably putting your panels on top of each other, enabling and disabling using some sort of code.

You did not upload your code snippets, so take the following and adapt yours accordingly.

For you to implement actual swiping, you have to position your panels next to each other inside a parent game object, let's call it `Swipeable`, and then move this parent game object around depending on the user's drag direction.

First, create the `Swipeable` game object and put your panels inside it, position them so they are next to each other from left to right. Position this game object so that the first panel is visible in the camera and the others are not just yet. Make sure the script that has `OnDrag` and `OnDragEnd` is attached to `Swipeable`.

Add these member variables to your class that has `OnDrag` and `OnDragEnd`

```
// At what percentage threshold should it swipe to the next panel smoothly
public float swipeThreshold = 0.2f;
// Duration it takes to smoothly swipe to another panel
public float swipeDuration = 0.3f;
// Maximum distance that you can drag, so you don't just continuously drag to from first to last panel
private readonly float _swipeDistance = Screen.width;
// Initial position of this game object, which should be the parent called Swipeable
private Vector3 _startPosition;
// Index of the current panel, starts 0 and reaches transform.childCount - 1
private int _currentPanelIndex;
```

Initialize the `_startPosition` on start to current position:

```
private void Start()
{
    _startPosition = transform.position;
}
```

Implement the following `OnDrag` method. This will move the game object around when you're dragging with rules, such as the first panel can't let you drag to its left, and you can't drag more than the limit distance:

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
     // Difference in the x value when dragging
     var movement = data.pressPosition.x - data.position.x;
     // Only care about updating the x value of the Transform when dragging
     float xPos;
        
     // If it's the first panel, only allow dragging to next panel
     // If it's the last panel, only allow dragging to previous panel
     // Otherwise allow dragging both directions
     if (_currentPanelIndex == 0)
     {
         xPos = Mathf.Clamp(_startPosition.x - movement, _startPosition.x - _swipeDistance, _startPosition.x);
     } else if (_currentPanelIndex == transform.childCount - 1)
     {
         xPos = Mathf.Clamp(_startPosition.x - movement, _startPosition.x, _startPosition.x + _swipeDistance);
     }
     else
     {
         xPos = Mathf.Clamp(_startPosition.x - movement, _startPosition.x - _swipeDistance, _startPosition.x + _swipeDistance);
     }
        
     // Update the x value of Transform when dragging
     transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, _startPosition.y, _startPosition.z);
}
```

Now to implement the `OnEndDrag` method. Here it will check if you surpassed the threshold or not. If you surpassed the threshold, it will move smoothly to the next panel. If not, it will move smoothly back to the start position of the current panel:

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
     // How much of the screen was dragged
     var threshold = (data.pressPosition.x - data.position.x) / Screen.width;

     // If it exceeds the swipe threshold and would swipe to a valid panel, then swipe to that panel
     if (Mathf.Abs(threshold) >= swipeThreshold)
     {
         if (threshold > 0 && _currentPanelIndex < transform.childCount - 1)
         {
             _startPosition.x -= Screen.width;
         }
         else if (threshold < 0 && _currentPanelIndex > 0)
         {
             _startPosition.x += Screen.width;
         }
     }
        
     // Move smoothly to next panel or back to current panel depending on threshold
     StartCoroutine(MoveSmoothly(transform.position, _startPosition, swipeDuration));
}
```

Finally, here is the code for the `MoveSmoothly` function:

```
IEnumrator MoveSmoothly(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float duration) 
{
    float t = 0f;
    while(t <= 1.0f) 
    {
        t+= Time.deltaTime / duration;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, t));
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!